# How to get the name of a form control in reactive forms?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

So i currently have a reactive form with controls nested inside of it. Something like this:

```
costForm = new FormGroup({
  year1: new FormGroup({
    mrc: new FormControl(''),
    otc: new FormControl(''),
  })
})
```

I loop over this form using a simple `Object.keys(costForm).forEach((controlName) => {...})` and then get the control with `this.costForm.get(controlName)` I then send over this control to various multiple function but it seems that now in one of the functions i need the controlName itself to check some conditions. Although I could send the control name to all the functions but that would be very useless in some of the functions. I have seen this fragment [Get name of Form Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47832981/get-name-of-form-control) (answer 2) but it has too loop over the parent controls again. Is there a better way to find the name of the control?

Comment: I updated answer

Answer (score 3):

When you are using reactive form you are getting access to controls.

```
Object.keys(this.costForm.controls).forEach((controlName) => {
console.log(controlName)})
```

To get one specific control:

this.costForm.get(’nameOfControl’)

Answer (score 2):

You need make a recursive function. You can think in a function that get a FomGroup or a FormArray

```
   loopGroup(form: FormGroup | FormArray) {
    if (form instanceof FormArray) {  //if is a FormArray
      form.controls.forEach(x => {
        if (x instanceof FormControl) this.makeSomething(x);
        if (x instanceof FormGroup || x instanceof FormArray)
         this.loopGroup(x);
      });
    } else {  //if is a FormGroup
      Object.keys(form.controls).forEach(key => {
        const control = form.get(key);
        if (control instanceof FormControl) this.makeSomething(control);
        if (control instanceof FormGroup || control instanceof FormArray)
         this.loopGroup(control);
      });
    }
  }

  makeSomething(control:AbstractControl){
      ...make something...
  }
```

You use as

```
  this.loopGroup(this.myForm)
```

But really I don't know want you want achieve.

**Update** About to get the "html tag", the problem is that a FormControl is not relationated with the html element(*). A FormControl exist independently is you has a input or not, so,e.g. you can not access to the attributes of the html tags from the FormControl

So we need take another aproach, that is create a simple directive that allow us get the NgControl and the htmlElement. Is we use some like

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'input'
})
export class HtmlControl{
   constructor(@Optional() private ngControl:NgControl,
               public elementRef:ElementRef){}

   isControl(control:AbstractControl)
   {
        return this.ngControl.control==control
   }
}
```

We can get all the "inputs" using ViewChildren

```
  @ViewChildren(HtmlControl) controls:QueryList<HtmlControl>
```

And we can do in our function makeSomething

```
  makeSomething(control:AbstractControl){
    const ctrl=this.controls.find(x=>x.isControl(control))
    console.log(ctrl.elementRef)
      ...make something...
  }
```

(*)Really a NgControl has two properties: control and valueAccessor, in valueAccessor._elementRef you has the elementRef and in control you has the FormControl, but I don't know how access to the NgControl of a FormControl

Comment: the thing is i already have the same recursive function. To loop over groups and control and a function like `makeSomething(x)` but then the thing is makeSomething also calls other functions which also uses control `x` but then some of the functions within the makeSomething require the name of the control `x` not just the FormControl instance itself. So for eg if `x` was named mrc then in one of the functions i need the name mrc

Comment: About to get the "html tag", the problem is that a FormControl is not relationated with the html element. I updated the question using a Directive that "relationate" the htmlElement and the control